# group pandas dataframe by paragraph

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas Dataframe with one column with text. The Dataframe has rows with linebreaks (\n).
Now I want to group all rows between two linebreaks.
example:

```
text_column
this is text
this is a new line

here starts a new paragraph
new line of new paragraph

next paragraph
...
```

I tried to mark the rows with linebreaks with:

```
txt["doc"]=txt.text.str.match('\n')
```

This command gives me a new column with true/false. This is not what I want. I look for this result:

```
text_column                                              paragraph
this is text this a new line                                 1
here starts a new paragraph new line of new paragraph        2
next paragraph                                               3
```

I hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each empty string contains `\n` only use `cumsum` for cumulative sum and pass to `groupby` for aggregate `join`, last remove possible trailing whitespaces and paragraph and add new column:

```
df = (txt.groupby(txt.text.str.match('\n').cumsum())['text']
         .agg(' '.join).str.strip().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
         .assign(paragraph = lambda x: range(1, len(x)+1)))

print (df)
                                                text  paragraph
0                    this is text this is a new line          1
1  here starts a new paragraph new line of new pa...          2
2                                     next paragraph          3
```